# XMLHttpRequest fails to send cookie if progress is tracked

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I've got a simple code that sends files to server from `https://app.myserver:4202` to `https://myserver/backend/upload.php`:

```
//script executed on`https://app.myserver:4202`
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://myserver.com/backend/upload.php");
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(fd); //fd is formdata from file input
```

yay, it successfully sends the files with cookie so I can perform user authentication in my upload.php script. Now, I also want to display progress bar so I changed the code to this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://myserver.com/backend/upload.php");
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        console.log("add upload event-listener" + evt.loaded + "/" + evt.total);
     }
  }, true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

Whoa, all hell broke loose! We have a CORS problem. Notice that I only added a progress tracker.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myserver/backend/upload.php' from origin 'https://myserver:4202' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I took great care to setup CORS correctly so this are `myserver` response headers that are relevant to CORS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://app.myserver.com:4202
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

They work well, if no progress info is desired, but fail when it is tracked.

So tell me, what am I missing out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have a CORS problem. Notice that I only added a progress tracker.

This behaviour is [defined in the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#request):

> Registering one or more event listeners on an XMLHttpRequestUpload object will result in a CORS-preflight request. (That is because registering an event listener causes the upload listener flag to be set, which in turn causes the use-CORS-preflight flag to be set.)

---

> I took great care to setup CORS correctly so this are myserver response headers that are relevant to CORS

Read the error message carefully:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myserver/backend/upload.php' from origin 'https://myserver:4202' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to **preflight request** doesn't pass access control check: It **does not have HTTP ok status**.

So the HTTP response headers you set aren't really relevant.

The browser is making the OPTIONS request to ask for permission to make the POST request and the server is responding with something other that `200 OK`.

Possibly it is sending `405 Method Not Allowed`. Check the Network tab of your developer tools to find out exactly what the HTTP response status is, and then adjust the server accordingly.

Comment: thanks for taking your time. I get a 400 Bad Request error and it is is triggered by my php script, because there is no cookie header attached in the request

Comment: Cookies are never sent in preflight requests. You'll need to fix the PHP so it can handle OPTIONS requests without them.